# Field Extensions

Tags: field-theory

Let $L/K$ a finite extension and $f(x)\in K[x]$ a non-linear irreducible polynomial. Prove that  if $\mathrm{gcd}\left( \mathrm{deg}(f) , \left[ L:K  \right]  \right)=1$ then $f(x)$ has no roots in $L$.

---

*Added: (Solution based on the answer below)*

Suppose $f(x)$ has a root in $L$, namely $\alpha$ and consider the extension $K(\alpha)/K$. Since $f$ is irreducible we have that $[K(\alpha) : K] = \mathrm{deg}(f) > 1$. On the other hand we have that $[L:K]=[L:K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]$. Then $[L:K]=[L:K(\alpha)](\mathrm{deg}(f))$ but this is imposible since $\mathrm{gcd}\left( \mathrm{deg}(f) , \left[ L:K  \right]  \right)=1$ and $\mathrm{deg}(f) > 1$.

Comment: I would just add "and $\mathrm{deg}(f)\gt 1$" at the end; otherwise, perfect. (It my even be okay without it; I just like hammering the nails in solidly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. What do you know about the degree $[K(\alpha):K]$ of an extension when $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial $g(x)\in K[x]$?
2. What do you know about the degrees $[L:K]$, $[K:F]$, and $[L:F]$ of extensions when you have a tower $F\subset K\subset L$ ?

Comment: WooW! I guess I was complicating a lot this problem. Thank a lot for your time. And sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: @Chu: Don't forget to formally accept an answer (the one you find most helpful) when you are satisfied. I might also suggest that you edit your question to add your solution if you with; that way we can help you with that too.

Comment: Ok. Do i post the solution within the space where the question go?

Comment: @Chu: You should have an [edit] button for the question. I would suggest editing it, and adding the solution at the bottom; perhaps divide it with a horizontal line `<hr/>` from the original text, mark it as an addition (say, by adding `*Edit:*` or `*Added:*`) and then write your solution. Or you can add your solution as an Answer if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I'll do that. :)